# When handling ChangeConflictException how should I prevent duplicate inserts?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

We have a WCF service as outlined below with the relevant extension methods.  We're getting duplicate inserts in the database for customer details.  I know why but I'm unsure of how to prevent it.

```cs
public interface ICustomerService
{
    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = false, IsInitiating = true, IsOneWay = false, AsyncPattern = false)]
    [FaultContract(typeof (ServiceFaultContract))]
    [FaultContract(typeof (ServiceTimeoutFaultContract))]
    DetailDataContract UpdateDetail(int entityId, RecordType recordType, string detailKey, string details);
}

[ServiceBehavior(TransactionAutoCompleteOnSessionClose = false, TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)]
[ExceptionShielding("ServiceLayerPolicy")]
public abstract class CustomerServiceBase : ServiceBase, ICustomerService
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    public virtual DetailDataContract UpdateDetail(int entityId, RecordType recordType, string detailKey, string details)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CustomerService : CustomerServiceBase
{
    public override DetailDataContract UpdateDetail(int entityId, string detailType, string detailData)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new DataContext())
            {
                var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == entityId);
                if(customer == null)
                    throw new Exception("Customer not found.");

                return customer.UpdateOrAddDetail(detailType, detailData).ToDataContract();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //logging code removed
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static class CustomerExtensions
{
    public static Detail UpdateOrAddDetail(this Customer customer, DataContext db, string type, string data)
    {
        //see if the customer has this detail
        var detail = customer.Details.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == type);
        //if the customer does, update it (code removed)
        //if the customer doesn't, insert it (code removed)

        customer.LastModified = DateTime.Now;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return detail;
    }
}

public static class DataContextExtensions
{
    public static void SaveChanges(this DataContext db, RefreshMode mode = RefreshMode.KeepChanges)
    {
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
        }
        catch (ChangeConflictException)
        {
            //logging code removed

            db.ChangeConflicts.ResolveAll(mode);

            //Resubmit
            try
            {
                db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //more logging code removed
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is pretty straight-forward, I think.  What is happening is that the client is calling to insert 3 details at once.  For reasons outside of the scope of this discussion, we have to update the customer last modified when updating or adding new details on a customer (the change on this field is important to other systems that use this database).

The first insert for the customer detail goes through just fine.  Where the problem happens is inserting the other details.  These are all threaded calls so it's attempting to do all this at the same time.  The insert for the second (and subsequent) detail when `db.SubmitChanges` is called works fine but it throws a `ChangeConflictException` when updating the `Customer` because it's `LastModified` was changed by the first detail insert on another thread.  I'm cool with that, so I just resolve it and try and submit the changes again.

And here's the problem.  When the second `SubmitChanges` is called the row gets inserted again.

The transaction is way above, handled by WCF.  I can't just rollback `Transaction.Current` as then I can't do anything.  I've tried to refresh the datacontext before the submit changes but I still get the `ChangeConflictException` and thus the duplicate row.

I need to be able to undo the inserts or not have the second inserts happen or have some way to rollback the current transaction but still be able to proceed with insert and resolving the conflict.

I end up with:

```
Id CustomerId Type Data
1 1 State Tx
2 1 City Austin
3 1 City Austin
4 1 MainTelephone 5125551212
5 1 MainTelephone 5125551212
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `UpdateOrAddDetail` method, you are first reading a value, then making a decision based on that value and finally saving the changes. If that method is run by two threads in parallell there will be duplicate values. You need to make sure that after the check has been done, no other instance can update the data before the data is saved.

To do that, you need to make two changes:

1. Change the isolation level of the transaction to Serializable, that will make sure that once one update is in progress, no other will be able to complete.

Unfortunately doing only that will give you a deadlock situation. The reason is that the read of the record with FirstOrDefault will only give a shared read lock, which is too weak in this case. This brings us to the second change.

2. Change the reading to use explicit SQL, that allows specification of an update lock which makes any other concurrent process block on the read.

```
var detail = db.ExecuteQuery<CustomerDetail>(
  "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetail WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE CustomerId = {0} AND Type = {1}",
  customer.CustomerId, type);
  customer.Details.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == type);
```

Comment: The threaded calls to add or update the customer details are made with different data. In the example given above we are calling to add customer details 3 times with different data but getting 5 inserts.  You are completely correct in that it currently isn't very thread safe if 2 clients tried to insert values for the same type of details but in our test bed we only have one client trying to add 3 different details.  This is a very minimalist example.  We have other instances where the same thing happens when there is an insert to a child that causes a change to the parent.

Comment: Please note that this only happens when we have a ChangeConflictException on the parent object.  That is why I'm making the assumption above that it is related to that.  Of course I could be wrong but we've isolated down the problem and consistently when we have a ChangeConflictException we get the duplicated inserts.

Comment: In the first comment I mean, "... are made with different types."  We are adding 3 unique detail types but getting 5 inserts.